# Jquery Galleria Classic Skin - thumbnail rows instead of scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, thumbnails, galleria

I'm looking for a way to have [Galleria](http://galleria.io/) classic skin have multiple rows of thumbnails rather than the scrolling thumbnail nav. Any idea where this would be housed?

Right now the thumbnails scroll left to right, I'd rather them drop to a new line after they exceed the width of the main photo frame and I'd rather not construct a whole table

I've tried expanding the thumbnail container to accommodate two rows, height-wise, but it doesn't know to drop them down.

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get two rows of thumbnails by altering the `galleria-thumbnails` div to 100px height and 100% width.

Edit: you may wish to change the height of `galleria-container` and `galleria-thumbnails-container` to accomodate the extra height of the `galleria-thumbnails` div

Comment: Forgive my obliviousness, but I don't see a galleria-thumbnails div in my .css; are you adding it? It's not in my html either, or the classic.js. </n00b>

Comment: Deleted last comment because I found a better way.  If you set the option `carousel: false`, it seems to automatically have the thumbnails flow into the next column.  Then the challenge is tweaking the CSS for the thumbnails container so that it is the right height so that the thumbnails don't flow over the actual image.  PS No n00b tag required - I cheated by changing the CSS in Chrome Dev tools once the page had loaded :P

Comment: I can find all the other settings to fix this, but I can't find where to put `carousel:false` I tried in `.galleria-carousel` and `.galleria-thumbnails-list` to no avail. I don't see a carousel listing in my `html` or my `classic.js` files so it has to be in `css`. But where? I even created `.galleria-carousel` and set `carousel:false` to no avail.

Comment: in my `galleria.classic.js` I put `Galleria.addTheme({
    name: 'classic',
    author: 'Galleria',
    css: 'galleria.classic.css',
    defaults: {
        transition: 'slide',
        thumbCrop:  'false', //width
  carousel: false,` and that seemed to do the trick. Now, like you said I just need to adjust and center it as well as move the containers and info button so they are in the correct place. I used [this documentation](http://galleria.io/docs/1.2/options/)

Comment: Sorry for being cryptic... glad you found a way.  You can also add carousel as an option when you are creating a new galleria instance  i.e. `$("#galleria").galleria({ carousel: false });`.  Your way is good though because it sets the theme default for all gallerias you create.

Answer (score 0):

The container holding the thumbnails needs its width reduced to the size of the widget as well, then the thumbnails will wrap onto the second row.